# Given set of number $\{{a_1}, ..., {a_n}\}$, how to know whether $b$ can be obtained by performing $XOR$ operation between number in the set?

Tags: commutative-algebra, boolean

For example, given the set {0011, 1001, 0110, 1110}, the number 1011 can be obtained by performing xor between number in the set
0011 xor 0110 xor 1110 = 0101 xor 1110 = 1011

Another example, given the set {0011, 1001, 0110}, the number 0111 is not in the set and cannot be obtained by performing xor between number in the set
0011 xor 1001 = 1010
0011 xor 0110 = 0101
1001 xor 0110 = 1111
0011 xor 1001 xor 0110 = 1010 xor 0110 = 1100

So given a set of number, how to know whether a number not in the set can be obtained by performing xor operation between number in the set ? trying one by one is simply impractical because i had to try whether the number can be obtained by xor-ing 2 number, or xor-ing 3 number, and so on until xor-ing n amount of number where n in the amount of number in the set.

Is there a shortcut to this?

Comment: This is linear algebra over the finite field $\mathbb F_2$. You want to know whether the vector $b$ is in the span of the vectors $\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$.

Comment: @mr_e_man oh thank you, if you dont mind may i ask a good book reference to learn about it ?